# Delete in Select Несколько вопросов и warning

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2

Сервер 5.7 
Пишу так получаю ошибку

```
   DELETE FROM agent_view_closure WHERE Agc_Path IN 
    SELECT CONCAT(savc.Agc_Path, CONCAT('-', 8)) AS path FROM agent_view_closure savc WHERE savc.Agc_Oag_Id_Desc = 4
```

> 11:40:56 Kernel error: Error( 1064 ) 42000: "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'avc WHERE avc.Agc_Path IN

Теперь пишу по отдельности

```
DELETE FROM agent_view_closure avc WHERE avc.Agc_Path IN ('4-8')
```

> 11:43:05 Kernel error: Error( 1064 ) 42000: "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'avc WHERE avc.Agc_Path IN
>   ('4-8')' at line 1"

Вот так срабатывает

```
DELETE FROM agent_view_closure WHERE Agc_Path IN ('4-8')
```

Но пишет Warning

```
11:44:07 Warning: 1681. 'EXTENDED' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
```

Дело в том что это нужно написать на Symfony

```
$into = $qb->select([
            $qb->expr()->concat('savc.path', $qb->expr()->concat("'-'", ':descendant'))
        ])
            ->from(AgentViewClosure::class, 'savc')
            ->where('savc.descendant = :agent')
            ->getDQL();

        $qb->resetDQLParts();

        $qb->delete()
            ->from(AgentViewClosure::class, 'avc')
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('avc.path', $into))
            ->setParameters([
                'descendant' => $descendant->getId(),
                'agent'      => $agent->getId()
            ]);
        $test = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Получаю ошибку схожу с первыми

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table
>   'agent_view_closure' for update in FROM clause

Есть у кого мысли как это решить?

Comment: На warning ответ похоже тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585144/did-mysql-5-7-9-remove-support-for-alter-ignore-table
А вот на остальное хз, в Delete  похоже нельзя писать алиас

Comment: Что вам нужно то? зачем `IN` в запросе, если синтаксис `IN(var1,var2,var3)` но у вас только одно значение.

Comment: @Naumov Представьте что их 2, дальше там написан Select  который может вернуть не одно значение а несколько, например 2 или 3 или даже пол сотни

Comment: А понял вообщето в первом запросе скобочек нехватает у вас получаеться сейчас `IN '4-8' ` вместо `IN ('4-8')` те должно быть что то подобное `IN(select id from user)` для примера.

Comment: @Naumov пробовал со скобками кавычками все варианты, проблема в том что удаление идет по той же таблице что и select, решается это с помощью join  такая же ситуация может быть и при update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В mysql нельзя удалять и одновременно выбирать из той же таблицы. Обходится через вложенный from-подзапрос или многотабличную форму delete. Подробней см [MySQL error 1093 и 1235](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/19.html)